# Is speaking during the megilla meakev?

Tags: megillat-esther, hefsek-interruption

If someone isn't following inside, "spaces out" a bit and, during the pause after the first perek, mistakenly started to say the pasuk "ish yehudi..."

If that person only said these two words and didn't miss any words from the baal kriah, does he need to hear the megila again?

Comment: This site avoids personal questions which are best answered by your rav. I allowed myself to edit to depersonalize. You can revert if you disagree

Comment: This question should be closed, as far as I can tell, per https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Answer (score 3):

The halacha is that one should hear every word of the megila ([Mishna Brura 690:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.690.5?lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en&p3=Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.692.2&lang3=bi&w3=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang4=en)) since

> according to many poskim (incl. the Rashba, Ran, and others), if one
>   misses hearing even one word of the Megillah, one has not fulfilled
>   one’s obligation (see [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=1902)).

At the same time, one is not permitted to talk at all while the Megillah is being read and until after the blessing of "Harav et riveinu." (see [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/260802/jewish/The-Laws-of-Reading-the-Megillah.htm)) based on [SA OC 692:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.692.2?lang=bi)

In the case where one spoke briefly but heard all the words, it seems from the Kaf Hachaim ([692:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.692.2?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.692.22.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)) and [Mishna Brura 692:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.692.2?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.692.9&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) that **one is not required to repeat the megila if he didn't miss a word.**

As always, do not believe what strangers write on the Internet and [ask your rav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi I asked said it's fine since I didn't miss any words. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear this. You might want to edit your question and add this - and ask for further sources to justify his answer. Otherwise, without your rabbi's name or sources, that statement is not so useful as an answer